# PHP Variable being read as empty

Tags: php, class, post

I have a class with a function, the function calls the variable and for some reason it shows up empty, when it is set at the beginning. (Not the full code by the way) (url is used as the path in the function variable)

```
    public      $domain         =   'http://rbx-js.herokuapp.com';
    protected   $key            =   '';         

    protected function post($url, $data)
    {
    foreach($data as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
    $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string,'&');

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$this->domain.$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($data));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    return $result;
    }
```

It would return something like this:
http:///getPlayers/retrieve/3e75c964ae

Comment: What is up with your tabs between variable assignment at the top and and indentation on the `post` function?

Comment: which variable is showing up empty?

Comment: I suspect the `$domain` property is overwritten elsewhere, for example in the class constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your variables in cosntruct:

```
public      $domain;
protected   $key;     

protected function __construct()
{
    $this->domain = 'http://rbx-js.herokuapp.com';
    $this->key    = '';
}

protected function post($url, $data)
{
    foreach($data as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
    $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string,'&');

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$this->domain.$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($data));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Why `init()`? You'll need to call the function manually. Why not just advise use of `__construct()`?

Comment: Yes indeed, I have edited the answer. I usually use init, but I am calling it from inherited custom base class.